# Escape "" characters to enter variable in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am sure this one is staring me in the face. Trying to increase the rotation on an object until i reaches a value. Getting an error as I am trying to escape the CSS part to enter my variable 'i'.

Can anybody see what may be wrong?

```
for(var i = 0; i < 200; i++){
  console.log(i);
  $('.rotateMe').css({"transform": "rotate("i"deg)"});
}
```

Thanks

Comment: The concatenation operator for strings is `+`

Comment: Note that you cannot do animation that way as there needs to be a delay between the animation events.   Try to use `css animation` instead, or `jquery animate`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to concatenate `variable` inside `string` with `+` , like this:

```
for(var i = 0; i < 200; i++){
  console.log(i);
  $('.rotateMe').css({"transform": "rotate("+i+"deg)"});
}
```

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
  $('.rotateMe').css({
    "transform": "rotate(" + i + "deg)"
  });
}
```

```css
.rotateMe {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="rotateMe"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the `+`

```
 for(var i = 0; i < 200; i++){
    console.log(i);
    $('.rotateMe').css({"transform": "rotate("+i+"deg)"});
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot concatenate strings like that in JS, try

```
"rotate("+i+"deg)"
```

Answer (score 1):

You have an error in your code:

```
for(var i = 0; i < 200; i++){
  console.log(i);
  $('.rotateMe').css({"transform": "rotate(" + i + "deg)"});
}
```

For string concatenation in javascript you must use the plus (+).